# Get data from 2 tables in one sql query

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables which are as below in SQL and I want to get data from these 2 tables which is shown as Expected result

[image: How do I achieve that in SQL?]

Comment: This explanation does not suffice. You want to combine records with the same `No` and `Month`? Is it guanranteed that there is always one record per `No` and `Month` in each table? Or can it be that a combination is only present in one table? Can it even happen that there are multiple entries? What to do then? Are the results always simply the sums of all records?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose values is columns 4,5,6 must be sum from T1 and T2:

```
SELECT
    t1.No, t1.Month, t1.Salary + t2.Salary,
    ( t1.PresenceTime + t2.PresenceTime ) AS PresenceTime,
    ( t1.AbsencePaidTime + t2.AbsencePaidTime ) AS AbsencePaidTime,
    ( t1.PresenceTargetTime + t2.PresenceTargetTime ) AS PresenceTargetTime
  FROM TABLE1 t1 JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.No=t2.No AND t1.Month=t2.Month;
```

Not sure whether JOIN only on `No` or `Month` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a join that you need, rather a UNION. You can do

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```